# How to distinguish between single slash for escaping vs windows file path?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a logger class in my JavaScript that has the following line at some point:

```js
// some function class that has `msg: string` variable
msg = msg.replace(/\\/g, '');
```

My logger has some syntax such as `--some string--` that gets a markup. But if someone wants to actually print `--` then they would escape it with `"\\-\\-some string\\-\\-"`.

Now this all works well. However, on a Windows machine, file paths use `\` and when I try to print for example `logger.info(process.cwd())`, that line `msg.replace(/\\/g, '')` replaces all the slashes in the path and I end up getting something like `C:userskoushadocumentsnode_modules`

How can I handle both windows file path and the ability to escape characters?

Comment: So you want keep single slashes but remove double slashes, is it accurate?

Comment: @skyboyer No. They are both `single` slashes. `\\-` is just the string `\-`. For the pov of the code, I want to be able to convert the string `\-foo` to `-foo` but keep  `C:\foo\bar` as is.

Comment: Sounds like you just want `.replace(/\\-/g, '-')`?

Comment: Notice that file paths may legimately contain `\-`, so you might actually need to do `logger.info(escape(process.cwd()))` or `logger.info("%s", process.cwd())` or something

Comment: @Kousha If they are single slashes, and `"\\"` is just the string escaping for a single (back)slash, maybe you should change the question title to ask about single (back)slashes.

Comment: @Bergi the problem is, I sometimes log a `JSON.stringify(someObj)` with this someObj having a key that contains a path. So I can't escape with aprior knowledge

Comment: @Kousha But you can escape the whole JSON, no? Or does `someObj` also contain some values where you do want to apply your `--…--` syntax?

Comment: @Bergi exactly, someObj will be a nested object, and some values are paths and some values are escaped characters. I think I need to have a recursive function that looks at each individual key, and check if it's path like or not and conditionally apply this.

Comment: @Kousha This is simply theoretically flawed. You cannot distinguish values where you want to apply formatting on your custom syntax from those where the very same syntax can appear randomly but that you don't want to format, by just looking at the value. If you try to do that, you'll end up introducing security issues just like the log4j vulnerability that's making the news currently. Keep them strictly separate, like in two different objects that are passed as different arguments to the logger. What exactly is your use case, what does "*gets a markup*" mean?